# 135mm rear end, 130mm rear wheel, Titanium frame

Tags: disc-brake, titanium

I'm looking at a Ti frame with a 135mm rear end, disc brake.  And I have invested in wheels for my commuter, which is disc brake... but a 130 mm spacing.

Is 5 mm enough of a concern -- impact to the frame, the disc brake setup -- that I should look for a frame with a 132.5 mm spacing if I want to be able to use wheels off my commuter?

Comment: Not ideal, but it'll work.  The thing to worry about is your chainline -- that it isn't thrown off too far (though 2.5mm is unlikely to have much effect).

Comment: Did you try the spacers?  Did it work?

Comment: Not yet, but it's back on my mind.  The shop told me the wheel in particular needs to be re-dished for 135 spacing as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add two 2.5mm spacers on each side, or even on the same side (or one 5mm spacer).

If you add to one side, you could even correct some perceived/subjective asymmetry, be it with chainline or with wheel dishing.

It's not impossible, if you use the wheel without spacers, that the dropouts get marked by the axle nuts, due to the slight twisting that will probably appear. Anyway, as others pointed, most probably that would not seriously damage anything else.

(More "anyway" yet, I would try the spacers first ;oP )

Answer (score 1):

5mm flex in either direction on a Ti frame should cause no issues at all.

I have done it with steel no issues in either direction. Even spread a 110mm redline SS steel frame to fit a 135mm wheel with no issues.

Comment: Nice to know it works. Actually, in this case, it would be only 2.5mm of flexion on each direction. Like you said, most probably no problem at all.